# Как сложить числа из столбца в Python?

Tags: python

У меня есть код:

```
for i in range(20):
    a = random.randint(0,101)
```

Который выдаёт мне столбец из чисел:

```
37
17
42
и т.д.
```

Вопрос, как сложить эти числа в одно целое? Я пробовал многие способы и искал ответы, но я совсем зелёный, и как бы я не пытался у меня выходит ошибка **int is not iterabl**.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Либо вручную складываете числа по мере генерации, либо организуете их в cписок и применяете встроенную функцию sum

```
summa = 0
for i in range(20):
   a = random.randint(0,101)
   summa += a

#
l = [random.randint(0,101) for _ in range(20)]  
summ = sum(l)
```